# How to pass a stored procedure as parameter to another stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

How to pass a stored procedure as parameter to another stored procedure? There are 2 SPs, `LOAD1` and `LOAD2`, and I want to pass `LOAD2` as parameter to the SP `LOAD1`.

Comment: I guess there is no way to pass a stored procedure as input parameter to another procedure. However you can pass the stored proc's name as parameter and then execute that proc with execute immediate.

Comment: You might want to check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2ptbrSpDkw